# Is it good practice to include other dom elements actions into another dom elements action like common actions for both in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it good practice code below?(jquery)

common.js (dom elements of two files written in same js action)

```
$('.list_item').click(function () {
   $('#yes_button').addClass('selected');
   $('#no_button').addClass('selected_no');
});
```

yes_button.html

```
<div class='list_item yes_class' > Muhammad s.a.w </div>
<div id='yes_button' > Yes </div>
```

no_button.html

```
<div class='list_item no_class'> Muhammad s.a.w </div>
<div id='no_button' > No </div>
```

is the above practice good or should we write like below

```
$('.yes_class').click(function () {
   $('#yes_button').addClass('selected');
});

$('.no_class').click(function () {
   $('#no_button').addClass('selected_no');
});
```

I have two files with same class for DOM elements, I'm writing JS code based on unique 
class name, my question is it the good practice to follow such way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a common class to your buttons and call them through that?

```
$('.list_item').click(function () {
   $('.button').addClass('selected');
});
```

If you want, you can be more specific about which button you are targeting like so

```
$('.list_item').click(function () {
   $(this).next('button').addClass('selected');
});
```

Assuming you keep the same structure of your html

```
<div class="listitem"></div>
<div class="button" id="..."></div>
```

Comment: my project scenorio is not as simple as mentioned in question, i've different properties for newly added class so i cannot use and i cannot use jquery next() function also  because my element is located in different place in dom.

Comment: i just answered the question based on the information you provided. 
If you want a better answer, please provide actual code or a better explanation of how your code is structured (jsfiddle helps a lot)